# Which set of APIs should be used for Office365 Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, office365api

Which set of APIs should be use to access Office365 sharepoint which includes both sharepoint2013 and sharepoint2016.

Have gone through the following APIs
1) Sharepoint2013 REST APIs(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx). 
2) OneDrive new APIs(https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs) through which we can access the Directory folder which contains directory and files. But the present focus of APIs are for OneDrive Personal and Business.

Apart from this is there any other APIs which can access the office365 sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SharePoint REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx) to retrieve, update, and manage data in Sharepoint Online ,you could find code samples and videos from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/starter-projects-and-code-samples).

With Graph API you could get files/users/groups ,but SharePoint sites and lists are not yet available via Microsoft Graph .

In addition ,you could also use SharePoint client object model (CSOM) to manage data in Sharepoint Online,please read below article:

[Connect to SharePoint Online using Client Object Model](https://sites.google.com/a/booleanarray.com/blog-sharepointfacts/home/SharePoint-Client-Object-Model/connecttosharepointonlineusingclientobjectmodelc)